# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near WHERE 1=0' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect to mySQL database using MySQL 5.2 ODBC Driver, tested the connection and it was successful but when I am running select queries on the database tables getting below error -

> The service was unable to retreive the results of the query. ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.40-community]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"dbtmsprod02"."twe_planning" ) T WHERE 1=0' at line 1

**Here is my SQL query :**

```
Select "plan_id", "plan_desc", "plan_status" From "dbtmsprod02"."twe_planning"
```

I am little to new this area, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Prabhu

Comment: Are you sure that's your whole query? The error says it isn't.

Comment: You clearly have NOT posted your whole query

Answer (score 3):

By default, MySQL is non-standard in that it uses double-quotes for string delimiters (identical to single-quotes).  Standard SQL uses double-quotes in the way you are using them, as delimiters for table and column identifiers.

You can use the [SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html) to make MySQL conform to ANSI SQL:

```
SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES
```

Or you can use MySQL's default identifier delimiter, the back-tick:

```
Select `plan_id`, `plan_desc`, `plan_status` From `dbtmsprod02`.`twe_planning`
```

Or you could just take out the quotes, because none of your identifiers need them.  Delimited identifiers are required if your identifiers contain special characters, whitespace, or SQL reserved words.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, it worked without the quotes but its only selecting the very first row yet there are thousands of records in the source table.

Comment: That's a separate issue and it can't be answered with the details you've given.  I suggest you open a new question, and include the full query and describe what you expect the result of the query to be.